# Clear Invalid Values from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets for this:

I have a spreadsheet which is basically a 4-week planner. Each day is divided into several slots, which can be assigned to any of our active clients. These cells have validation rules which reject invalid values.

The data that is permitted by the validation rules is sourced from a list on a separate sheet, which filters out clients when their status is changed from 'Active' to 'Cancelled', meaning they can no longer be assigned. The status is changed manually. Once an assigned client changes to 'Cancelled', it becomes an invalid client on the calendar.

Is there a way, using scripts, to find and clear the values of cells containing these invalid values? I've included a screen clipping below. The red corner is the invalid value.

I already have the `onEdit` trigger set up to run code, this will be calling a function to deal with this specific area.

[screen clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kckJb.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  The first thing that needs to be established, is what will trigger the code to check for the invalid value?  How does the assigned client get changed to "Cancelled"?  Someone edited a cell?  You can have code run when an edit happens.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with this the information you needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //First check if you want the entire code to execute
  if (myNeededCondtion !=== "theValueToMach") {
    //End the code here
    return;
  }

  var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = mySpreadsheet.getSheetByName("name of sheet");

  var arrayOfColumnValues = theSheet.getRange(row to start at, column to start at, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

  var i=0;
  var thisValue = "";

  for (i=0;i<arrayOfColumnValues.length;i+=1) {
    thisValue = arrayOfColumnValues[i][0];
    if (thisValue==="Cancelled") {
      //Set the cell value to a blank string
      theSheet.getRange(i, column).setValue("");
    };
  };
};
```

You need to figure out what the range value parameters need to be, and edit the code.  Add the correct sheet name to the `getSheetByName` method.  Note that `getValues()` returns a two dimensional array.  Each inner array represents a row.  If you only get one column of data, then each inner array will only have one element in it.  Arrays are indexed starting at zero.