# Clear cells returning invalid values

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've written the code below (multiple dependent dropdowns) which is now working. I now want to build a final step into this script which will **clear any invalid values entered**. I'm not really finding many threads/guides/videos which touch on this.

The only other thread here is this - [Clear Invalid Values from Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914982/clear-invalid-values-from-spreadsheet), but from the looks of this code it can only clear specific values. When I need the script to clear anything invalid.

**Invalid in this context** = #1 Pasting text from another spreadsheet (instead of using dropdowns) into 1st column or #2 Selecting 1st column, then 2nd column, then going back and changing 1st column which then can invalidate the 2nd column.

[image] - Example showing exactly what I mean. 1st row all fine. 2nd row matches #2 from paragraph above. 3rd row matches #1 from paragraph above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function dropdown() {
  var activeCell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeRow=activeCell.getRow()
  var activeCol=activeCell.getColumn()
  var activeValue=activeCell.getValue()
  var activeSheet=activeCell.getSheet()

  if(activeSheet.getName()=="Main Sheet" && activeRow>1 && activeCol==3){
    var worksheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var spreadsheet=worksheet.getSheetByName("Data")
    var data=spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var list=data.filter(row=>row[0]==activeValue).map(row=>row[1])
    var validation=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build()
    activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validation)
}
}

function onEdit(){
  dropdown()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add text to end of string if data validation is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684788/add-text-to-end-of-string-if-data-validation-is-invalid)

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what "valid' means in your desired context.

Comment: Please EDIT your question rather than adding comments.

Comment: Apologies, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && (e.range.columnStart == 3 || e.range.columnStart == 1)) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate")
    let rule = e.range.getDataValidation();
    if (rule) {
      if (!~rule.getCriteriaValues()[0].indexOf(e.value)) {
        e.range.setValue('');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My spreadsheets now disallow invalid entrees and clear the invalid values all by themselves and disable the onEdit trigger in those cases.

Comment: Apologies, very new to this still. Does your section of code replace my rows 18 - 20? Replacing Sheet0 of course.

Comment: No it just clears cell returning invalid values

Comment: So I tried inserting that block of code before and after my existing "function onEdit()" block, didn't remove invalid values from my 1st column.

Comment: It only works on column 3 and you may have to change the sheet name.  I don't mean to be critical or sarcastic or hurtful in anyway but were all supposed programmers here.  So sometimes getting some code to work means having to put on our thinking cap.  I'm sorry but it's a reality.

Comment: Yes I did change the values (including sheet name) to match the code as I'd made a few updates since posting the initial question above.

Comment: That should work for columns  one or three